# Get facebook image by specific size

Tags: php, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

I need to get a photo from facebook wirh exactly size f.e. 300px width and 300px height, is there any way how to do it? I have ID of photo but i dont know how to use it.

A part from this issue was resolving here [Link to Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885522/how-to-get-a-specific-size-album-photo%20but%20unsuccesfeully) but unsuccesfeully.

I know it is possible with profile picture:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/redbull/picture?width=300&height=300
```

But it is possible with any photo? I think is way, via graph.facebook.com and specifying size of returning image, but i dont know how. :)

Comment: try https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/photo

Comment: if i write url: https://graph.facebook.com/[photoId]
the response is {
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Facebook image certain size go to this website it allows you to resize the image crop etc. http://www.picresize.com/

Comment: i dont think is ok about privacy rules of facebook.

Comment: It is you profile picture so you can resize how you want it is not breakuing any privacy rules.

Comment: i dont need for my picture but for other people pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Any valid access token for any photo with public privacy settings.

try

```
https://graph.facebook.com/photo_id?access_token={access_token}&height=25px&width=25px
```

For more :-https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/photo

or try

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/album/picture

Comment: That's not correct I think. At least not working for me. And having two "?" in the URL is not really good either.

Comment: this access_token=app_id|app_secret will be enough?

Comment: may be else you need user access token

Comment: I'm trying it directly in the Graph Explorer!

Comment: you have experiencie with it? 
i am using php Facebook->api.

Comment: The queries you can use are the same, only that you have direct visual results without coding PHP or something: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no way to do this. Have a look at the Photo docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/photo/ and you'll see that the photos are only available in max. four sizes.

The problem is anyway that you don't know the the photo's aspect ratio, so that you can also "scale" the image down by setting either the width or height attribute of the image tag.

Comment: yes, your are right i am using this way. Sometimes it returns four sizes of image, sometimes nine size, cause of original size of image. 
But i think if this it is possible with profile picture
https://graph.facebook.com/redbull/picture?width=300&height=300
why it cant be possible with any picture on facebook?

Comment: You already linked a good answer in your question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885522/how-to-get-a-specific-size-album-photo?answertab=votes#tab-top There's a difference between `picture` and `photo`

Comment: I added link to that topic when i was created this topic :)

Comment: Yeah, and? You more or less gave the link to the answer yourself, why do you post the question if you know that it's not working?

Comment: i am sure is way :) but that topic could not find it.